# Full Text Search Querying not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, full-text-search

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 developer edition.

I've ran the following:

```
exec sp_fulltext_database 'enable'
```

I then created a table with a FileType column and a FileContent column with a datatype of VARBINARY(MAX). I then right clicked on the table and defined the full text catalog using the primary key, they fileType column and the FileContent column. I then uploaded a document (using this helper method in C#)

```
// <summary>
    /// Read the file into a byte array for full text search
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputStream"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private byte[] GetFile(Stream inputStream)
    {
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(inputStream);

        byte[] file = br.ReadBytes((int)inputStream.Length);

        br.Close();
        inputStream.Close();

        return file;
    }
```

The file is uploaded to SQL server and I can see the binary data within the FileContent column.

I am now attempting to query the full text catalog:

```
SELECT * FROM Entities.Documents
WHERE CONTAINS(FileContent, 'tablesorting')

SELECT * FROM Entities.Documents
WHERE CONTAINS(FileContent, 'Tablesorting')

SELECT * FROM Entities.Documents
WHERE FREETEXT(FileContent, 'tablesorting')

SELECT * FROM Entities.Documents
WHERE FREETEXT(FileContent, 'Tablesorting')
```

None of these return any data, even though the document I uploaded (an Excel spread sheet version 2010) contains the word tablesorting.

Any advice? Thanks

UPDATE

It appears that the SQL Server box can't use Full Text Search with docx, xlsx etc.

This seems incredible considering Office switched to this format in 2007 and I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and the new document types aren't even registered.

Microsoft at it's best!

Thanks for the contributions.

Comment: How do you write the file in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instruct SQL Server to use the document filters installed in the OS. Also, you need to store the type of the document along with the binary to let the FT engine use the right filter. have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142531.aspx).